# Left & Right Cosets of a Kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we let $\phi:\mathbb R^*\to \mathbb R^*$ under multiplication be given by $\phi(x)=$| $x$ |.

What are the left and right cosets of the kernel? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: start with the easier question - what is the kernel?

Comment: Yes you are right. Okay, now what's the definition of a coset?

Answer (score 4):

Kernel is the set of  elements which map to identity under $\phi$

$Ker(\phi)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^*: \phi(x)=1\}$

$Ker(\phi)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^*: |x|=1\}$

Now which elements in $\mathbb{R}^*$ satisfy this?

**Edit (Details):**

You have $Ker(\phi)=\{1,-1\}$

> **Definition of Cosets:** If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then
>
> > **(i)** **a left coset of H in G** is defined as
>
> $gH=\{gh:h\in H\}$ where $g$ is a fixed element of $G$
>
> i.e. if $H=\{h_1,h_2,\ldots,h_k\}$, then $gH=\{g\cdot h_1,g\cdot h_2,\ldots,g\cdot h_k\}$. Same is the case when $H$ is not finite.
>
> > **(ii)** Similarly, **a right coset of H in G** is defined as
>
> $Hg=\{hg:h\in H\}$ where $g$ is a fixed element of $G$

**Note:** In your case, the left and right cosets are equal **(Since $\mathbb{R}^*$ is abelian)**

You can see it **for the finite case** below.

> Suppose $H=\{h_1,h_2,\ldots,h_k\}$
>
> Let $g\in G$ be arbitrary, then
>
> $gH=\{g\cdot h_1,g\cdot h_2,\ldots,g\cdot h_k\}=\{h_1\cdot g,h_2\cdot g,\ldots,h_k\cdot g\}=Hg$

Now coming back to your question, let $r\in\mathbb{R}^*$

$$r\cdot Ker(\phi)=Ker(\phi)\cdot r=\{-r,r\}$$

> So, the **set of left cosets** of $Ker(\phi)$ in $\mathbb{R}^*$ is $S=\{\{-r,r\}:r\in \mathbb{R^*}\}$
>
> **NOTE:** This is also the **set of right cosets** of $Ker(\phi)$ in $\mathbb{R}^*$

Comment: Yes, and the cosets of the kernel?

Comment: @user123652: I edited the post. Take a look at it.